# R create skewed distribution using stat_function

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I have this code here using ggplot2 and the function stat_function(). I'm using it to create a sample normal distribution with mean of 100 and standard deviation of 15 (IQ).

```
   ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 200)), aes(x)) +
      stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                    geom = "area", fill = '#1e466e', alpha = 0.5, 
                    args = list(
                      mean = 100,
                      sd = 15))
```

Is there a way to adjust this sample distribution so that it is not normal but skewed? And is there a way to play with the kurtosis also? I tried typing help(dnorm) and then reading the documentation but I didn't see any argument for skewness or kurtosis... which I guess makes sense because if I played with the third and fourth moment it wouldn't be a normal distribution so why would it be called 'dnorm'... But I'm trying to figure out how I can create a sample distribution with mean of 100 and standard deviation of 15 that has a different skewness or kurtosis. I'm just practicing here.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). In R, there is a `rbeta` function. But note that if you fix mean and variance, then alpha and beta will also be fixed. I don't think you can generate distributions with arbitrary skewness and kurtosis with fixed mean and variance.

Comment: You should take a look at the `dsn()` function in the `sn` package - I think it will do what you want.

Comment: I just tried to create what I think is a normal distribution using rbeta normal_distribution <- rbeta(100000,5,5)
normal_distribution <- as.data.frame(normal_distribution)
but when I put that against a q-q plot it doesn't look entirely normal to me - there's a sort of tail on each end like maybe too many values in middle

Comment: I'll check out sn package thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the t-distribution. A t-distribution has higher kurtosis than a normal distribution. As far as I know, base R does not support skew a for t-distributions. However, the package `skewt` provides the option for you to generate a t-distribution with a named skew:

```r
library(skewt)
x <- x=seq(-1,1,0.05)
y <- dskt(x=seq(-1,1,0.05), df=10, gamma=2)
plot(x, y)
```

The quantiles you get here are the standardised quantiles (mean is 0). You could calculate unstandardised quantiles by multiplying by the standard deviation and adding the mean (reverse standardise of sorts).

```
mean <- 100
sd <- 15
x1 <- x*sd + mean
plot(x1,y)
```

It depends what you wish to show. A normal distribution with fatter tails (larger kurtosis) is a t-distribution with n degrees of freedom. A t-distribution with different skew gamma is another layer on top.